# Why type has no __class_getitem__ method or __getitem__ method in Python3.10?

Tags: python, typing, magic-methods

Refer to Python documentation [`__class_getitem__`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__class_getitem__):

> A class can *generally* only be parameterized if it defines the special class method `__class_getitem__()`.

And [typing.Type](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#typing.Type):

> *Deprecated since version 3.9:* [`builtins.type`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#type) now supports `[]`. See [PEP 585](https://peps.python.org/pep-0585/) and [Generic Alias Type](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#types-genericalias).

This means that after version 3.9, we can use `type[class]` instead of `typing.Type[class]`, but in pycharm, when I use the former, the IDE tells me:

> Class `type` undefined `__getitem__`, therefore, the `[]` operator cannot be used on its instance.

And I confirmed this in interactive Python:

```
Python 3.10.5 (tags/v3.10.5:f377153, Jun  6 2022, 16:14:13) [MSC v.1929 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> list[int]
list[int]
>>> list.__class_getitem__(int)
list[int]
>>> type[int]
type[int]
>>> type.__class_getitem__(int)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: type object 'type' has no attribute '__class_getitem__'
>>> type.__getitem__(int)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: type object 'type' has no attribute '__getitem__'. Did you mean: '__setattr__'?
```

I noticed that "generally" is marked in italics in the first document, which means that it is not guaranteed to be correct for all types, so it does not mean that the document is wrong here. But I don't understand why Python adopt a special implementation for `type` (Because it is a metaclass?). The constant warnings of the IDE may make me give up using `type` and use `typing.Type` instead.

**Update:**

From the first document, we can know the reason why type doesn't implement the `__getitem__` method:

> Usually, the [subscription](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#subscriptions) of an object using square brackets will call the [`__getitem__()`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__getitem__) instance method defined on the object’s class. However, if the object being subscribed is itself a class, the class method [`__class_getitem__()`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__class_getitem__) may be called instead. `__class_getitem__()` should return a [GenericAlias](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#types-genericalias) object if it is properly defined.

Therefore, `type` does not implement `__getitem__` to avoid the occurrence of types similar to `int[str]`. However, this is not the reason why type doesn't implement `__class_getitem__`. Even if it has this implementation, according to the document description, it will not affect the instance of `type`.

Comment: This is basically just a bug in PyCharm (https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/PY-42418/Support-PEP-585-generic-standard-collections), so I'm not sure what the actual question is to answer ..

Comment: @wim I don't think it's all pycharm's fault, because type does lack the `__class_getitem__` method.

Comment: No that's still PyCharm's fault, it just says that their means of determining when a class is subscriptable is too blunt.

Comment: @wim Well, let's ignore the problem of pycharm for the time being. Even so, type is different from other indexable classes except that it lacks `__class_getitem__`. What is the reason for this implementation of Python?

Comment: I can only guess, but perhaps it's done that way so that non-container classes such as `str` and `int` (which are instances of type) don't end up with a `__class_getitem__`, because something like `int[str]` would be nonsense.

Comment: OK, I've found some evidence to that effect in a source code comment from Guido [here](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/934b25dcc492dcbca4da9d63d0d71dc940fc0375/Objects/abstract.c#L180-L183), which went in with PR [#18239](https://github.com/python/cpython/pull/18239).

Comment: @wim This is very strange. Describing the `__getitem__` method according to the document does result in `int[str]`, but `__class_getitem__` doesn't seem to.

Comment: `__class_getitem__` on `type` would make all your metaclasses subclassable (generic) - and they aren't.

Comment: So yes, pycharm as usual does something odd (lookup of `__getitem__` cannot be explained here), yes, `type` misses `__class_getitem__` (probably by the reason above). Word "generally" in docs quote, IMO, refers to `__getitem__` on metaclass: it is alternative to `__class_getitem__` (with higher precedence), and `type` is just an extreme corner case without analogues. Link by @wim proofs that `type` is subscriptable because it is specialcased in general `__getitem__` implementation and not because it implements some methods.